# NodeJS - How to use express instance as singleton(?) in any file

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Project structure

```
app.js
lib
    model
        User.js
        Product.js
routes
    .....
```

---

I want to execute

```
app.param('PARAMNAME');
```

in each model files silently.
But I don't have access to express js instance in model files.

How can I do this without methods like "init(app)"?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is through your controller. You have access to the `app` object in the request object in your controllers (routes). From your controller you can pass either the `app` object or the specific value `app.param('PARAMNAME')` to your model. with this approach your code would look more or less like this:

In your app.js

```
app.get('/someurl', someController.someMethod);
```

In someController.js

```
exports.someMethod = function(req, res) {
    // you have access to the "app" object here
    var paramName = req.app.param('PARAMNAME');
    // pass the value to your model
    yourModel.someMethod(paramName);
    // the rest of your controller code
}
```